# ggplot statbin with labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

How to get rid of the zero labels?

[image: ggplot statbin]

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=value)) + 
  stat_bin(binwidth=200) + 
  stat_bin(binwidth=200, geom="text", aes(label=..count..))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the argument `drop` for `stat_bin`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=value)) + 
  stat_bin(binwidth=200) + 
  stat_bin(binwidth=200, geom="text", aes(label=..count..), drop=TRUE)
```

> drop
>   If TRUE, remove all bins with zero counts

Since the argument `drop` is only set to `TRUE` in the plot for the text, only the label is dropped.

Answer (score 3):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=value)) + 
  stat_bin(binwidth=200) + 
  stat_bin(binwidth=200, geom="text", 
           aes(label=ifelse(..count.. == 0, "", ..count..)))
```

Comment: thanks mate, I ended needing both your answers, this is great :)